# Selection Sorting with ArrayLists

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have an arrayList of Students in my main class called S... of objects type student. In "s", i need to  sort my Students in my arrayList "S" by the registrationNumber they have, smaller to higher.

I tried many ways, but cannot get it to work...

```
public static void sort(){
            int small;
            for (int i=0; i < s.size() -1;i++){
            small = i;
                for (int ind = i + 1; ind< s.size(); ind++ ){
                if( stud.get(ind).getRegNum() < s.get(small).getRegNum() ){
                    small = ind;
                    swap(i, small);
                }
            }
          }
       }

      public static void swap(int one,int two){
            }
```

Comment: What ways did you try and didn't work? Did you use Arrays.sort() for this?

Comment: Please show what you have tried?

Comment: Thats what I tried... I dont know what to put in the swap, but im not sure void sort() is correct either

Answer (score 1):

1. Call `Collections.sort(yourStudentList);`
2. Your student class have to implement the interface Comparable
3. Override the `comparteTo()` method of the interface.

That's it!

Example for a comparator(assume `registrationNumber` is an integer):

```
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Student o) {
        if(null== o)
            return 1;   
        if(registrationNumber == 0 && o.registrationNumber==0)
            return 0;
        if(registrationNumber == 0 && o.registrationNumber!=0)
            return -1;
        if(registrationNumber != 0 && o.registrationNumber==0)
            return 1;
        return o.registrationNumber.compareTo(registrationNumber);
    }

return 1 //when o is less than this
return -1 //when o is bigger than this
return 0 //when they are equal
```

**EDIT** If you need to use selectionsort, than you need this comparator too and the interface compareable. But then you only have so creat a custom `sort()` function which implements the selectionsort algorithm.

Comment: Alternatively you can implement separate `Comparator` by registration number.

Comment: I need to use a algorithm, an not the ones already in Java :/

Answer (score 1):

You should check out java collections.
see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html

I assume that your student class has a public variable registrationNumber

```
public class StudentComparator implements Comparator<Student>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
        return (o1.registrationNumber>o2.registrationNumber);
    }
}
```

somewhere call:
    Collections.sort(students, new StudentComparator ());